# Abstract classes in java not taking any value

Tags: java, abstract

I am having a problem with abstract classes, the code runs but it won't take any value , it prints "0.0" everywhere, I'm thinking it is an acces problem.I have to make an abstract base class called "Point" where i declare the 3 coordinates of a point, then i have to calculate the area , volume and center point of a cube and a sphere .Also if something doesn't look good, needs formating, or don't understand a word, please tell me.Thank you.

```
   //this is the base class 

public abstract class Punct
{
public double x,y,z;
    Punct(double x,double y, double z)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
public double getX()
{
    return x;
}

public double getY()
{
    return y;
}
public double getZ()
{
    return z;
}
}
```

Then the sphere

```
//This is the sphere class that extends the Point class

public class Sfera extends Punct
{
    private double aria,volumul,raza,centrul;

    Sfera(double x, double y, double z,double aria,double volumul,
        double centrul,double raza)
    {
        super(x, y, z);
        this.aria=aria;
        this.volumul=volumul;
        this.centrul=centrul;
        this.raza=raza;
    }


public double getRaza(Punct p1,Punct p2)
    {
        raza=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y, 2)+Math.pow(p2.z-p1.z, 2));
        return raza;
    }

    public double getAria()
    {
        aria=4*Math.PI*raza*raza;
        return aria;
    }
public double getVolumul()
{
    volumul=4/3*Math.PI*raza*raza*raza;
    return volumul;
}

public double getCentrul(Punct p1)
{

    return centrul;
}


}
```

The Cube

```
//this is the cube
public class Cub extends Punct
{

    double latura,aria,volumul,centrul;

    Cub(double x, double y, double z,double latura, double aria,double volumul, double centrul) 
    {
        super(x, y, z);
        this.latura=latura;
        this.aria=aria;
        this.volumul=volumul;
        this.centrul=centrul;

    }
    public double getLatura(Punct p1,Punct p2)
    {
        latura=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y, 2)+Math.pow(p2.z-p1.z, 2));
        return latura;
    }
    public double getAria()
    {
        aria=6*Math.pow(latura, 2);
        return aria;
    }
    public double getVolumul()
    {
        volumul=latura*latura*latura;
        return volumul;
    }



}
```

And the Test Class where i have the main

```
//this is the Test class

public class TestTema
{
    public static void main(String[] args_)
    {
        Punct p1=new Punct(2, 2, 2) {};
        Sfera obSfera=new Sfera(1,2,3,1,1,1,1);
        System.out.println("Raza sfera:" + obSfera.getRaza(p1,p1));
        System.out.println("Aria sfera=" + obSfera.getAria());
        System.out.println("Volum sfera= " +obSfera.getVolumul());
    //  System.out.println("Centrul= "+obSfera.getSuprafata());

        Cub obCub=new Cub(1,2,3,1,1,1,1);

        System.out.println("Lungime latura cub:"+obCub.getLatura(p1,p1));
        System.out.println("Aria cubului="+obCub.getAria());
        System.out.println("Volumul cubului="+obCub.getVolumul());
    //  System.out.println("Suprafata="+obCub.getCentrul());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is really wrong. Sfera has a method `getRaza()` that computes the distance between two points. There's no reason to use a Sphere to compute the distance betwwen two points. This should be an instance method of Punct, that should take another point as argument.

But there's worse: instead of just computing the distance between two points, it stores this distance in the Sphere, overwriting its previous raza (not sure why a sphere has a distance):

```
raza=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y, 2)+Math.pow(p2.z-p1.z, 2));
```

You made the same mistake in several other methods: get methods should not change the state of the object.

Now, let's see your code. You start by calling

```
obSfera.getRaza(p1,p1)
```

That computes the distance between p1 and itself, so the answer is 0, and this distance is stored in the Sphere (as explained above). So, after this line of code, you've set the sphere's raza to 0. You then execute

```
obSfera.getAria()
```

and this method does

```
aria=4*Math.PI*raza*raza;
return aria;
```

so, once again, instead of just returning the area of the sphere, it overwrites its area with the computed value, which is 0 since you've set raza to 0 before.

Here's how a sphere class could look like:

```
public class Sphere {
    private final double radius;

    public Sphere(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return 4 * Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
    }


    public double getVolume() {
        return (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius * this.radius;
    }
}
```

Key points:

- its fields are final: they can't change.
- there is no need to store the volume and the area as fields, since they are derived from the radius
- getters don't try to modify the object. They just compute a value and return it.

Comment: After some time i realised that i am calculating the distance between 2 points with the same value ( only one point), the program works now after declaring two points, but i see that i could improve my code with your answer, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also i calculated getRaza() in sphere because in my language "Raza" is Radius so i want to calculate the radius inside the Sphere class, but i am seeing the flaws of my code and the possibility to make it better

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same point (p1) to calculate raza, thus replacing the value you used in the constructor. And then you used raza to calculate the other values in the Sfera class.
In the Cub class you are doing the same, so the programm is doing what it is supposed to do. If you calculate those things between the point and itself it will give you 0.
As a result the values you used in your constructor where overwritten by your methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Raza sfera:" + obSfera.getRaza(p1,p1));
```

Sorry, I can't translate what is `Raza`, but this method calculates distance between two points.
You pass into `getRaza` the same point. Distance between two identical points is zero. That is why `getRaza` returns zero.

You assign distance between points to internal field `Sfera::raza` inthe method `getRaza`

```
public double getRaza(Punct p1,Punct p2)
{
    raza=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)+Math.pow(p2.y-p1.y, 2)+Math.pow(p2.z-p1.z, 2));
    return raza;
}
```

So after calling `obSfera.getRaza(p1,p1)` the field `obSfera.raza` equals to zero.

All other methods use `obSfera.raza` in their formulas:

```
public double getAria()
{
    aria=4*Math.PI*raza*raza;
    return aria;
}

public double getVolumul()
{
    volumul=4/3*Math.PI*raza*raza*raza;
    return volumul;
}
```

Put `raza` value into your formulas:

- `volumul = 4/3*Math.PI*raza*raza*raza = 4/3*Math.PI*0*0*0 = 0`
- `aria = 4*Math.PI*raza*raza = aria=4*Math.PI*0*0`

The same is happening with the object `obCub`

Answer (score 0):

create another object for `class Punct` and rewrite the code like below:

```
public class TestTema
{
    public static void main(String[] args_)
    {
        Punct p1=new Punct(2, 2, 2) {};
        Punct p2=new Punct(3, 3, 3) {};
        Sfera obSfera=new Sfera(1,2,3,1,1,1,1);
        System.out.println("Raza sfera:" + obSfera.getRaza(p1,p2));
        System.out.println("Aria sfera=" + obSfera.getAria());
        System.out.println("Volum sfera= " +obSfera.getVolumul());
    //  System.out.println("Centrul= "+obSfera.getSuprafata());

        Cub obCub=new Cub(1,2,3,1,1,1,1);

        System.out.println("Lungime latura cub:"+obCub.getLatura(p1,p2));
        System.out.println("Aria cubului="+obCub.getAria());
        System.out.println("Volumul cubului="+obCub.getVolumul());
    //  System.out.println("Suprafata="+obCub.getCentrul());
    }

}
```

classes `Cub` and `Sfera` both refering the same object p1, so the distance value `Math.pow(p2.x-p1.x,2)` always be `0`.